# Removing the page flicker when loading javascript/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried putting the inline javascript code after`</body>` , but it didn't help.

HTML code:

```
<html>  
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title> Foodstant Delivery </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="testCSS.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.booklet.1.4.0.css" media="screen" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.booklet.1.4.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="container">
        <div id="numb1">    
                <img src="images/number4.png" />
            </div> 

        <figure id="logo"> 
            <img src="images/logo23.png" alt="Foodstant Delivery logo" />
        </figure>   

        <figure id="abtex">
            <img src="images/abtext126.png" />
        </figure>   
    <div class="Navigation">
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li class="OP"><a href="testHP.html"><img src="images/house.png" width="40" height="32" /></a>
                </li>   
                <li class="OP" id="OPM1"><img src="images/order.png"   /><a  href="Orders.html">Orders</a></li>
                <li class="OP" id="OPM"><img src="images/menupic3.png" /><a  href="Menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="OP"> <img src="images/contact.png" /><a href="#">Contact</a>
                        <div class="extended">
                            <div class="arrow-container"><div class="arrow-up"></div></div>

                            <ul class="smallNav">
                                <li><a href="#">+65-65553333</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/yourfanpage/12345678" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://twitter.com/yourtwitter" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
                                <li><a href="www.gmail.com" target="_blank">enquiry [at] foodstant [dot] com</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>


                <li class="OP"><img src="images/Pen.png"  /><a href="AboutUs2.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="OP"><img src="images/pin.png"   /><a  href="Jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>  


        <span id="papersl">
            <img src="images/paperslant5.png" />
        </span>

    <div id="mybook">
        <div> 
            <img src="images/CC1.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </div>
        <div> 
            <img src="images/WC.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </div>
        <div> 
            <img src="images/ss1.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </div>
        <div> 
            <img src="images/beverages.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>


        <form action="" id="search-form" class="SF">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="text" id="search" name="search" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search...';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search...') {this.value = '';}" value="Search..." class="searchfield" />
                <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <figure id="foot">
            <img src="images/footer-comb1.png" usemap="#green" border="0">

            <map name="green">

            <area shape="rect" coords="503,41,614,85" href="http://www.trees.com/furniture.html">
            <area shape="rect" coords="710,44,866,84"  href="#0" id="se" >
            </map>
        </figure>   

</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#numb1').hide().delay(800).fadeIn('normal');

                $('#se').click(function() {
                    $('.SF').css('visibility','visible');

                });     

                $(function() {
                    $('#mybook').booklet({
                   width:600,
                     height:350
                });
            });
            });

        </script>

    </html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;

}


body {
    background-image: url('images/BG-W1.png');
    font-family: 'Conv_LITHOSPRO-REGULAR',Verdana,Helvetica,'Courier New',sans-serif;
    /*height: 800px !important;*/

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_LITHOSPRO-REGULAR';
    src: url('fonts/LITHOSPRO-REGULAR.eot');
    src: url('fonts/LITHOSPRO-REGULAR.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/LITHOSPRO-REGULAR.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/LITHOSPRO-REGULAR.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/LITHOSPRO-REGULAR.svg') format('svg');
}

#container{
    max-width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 0 auto;
    /*height: 762px !important;*/
    /*border: 2px solid blue;*/

}

#logo {
    float:left;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    height: 180px;
}

#abtex {
    float: left;
        /*border: 1px solid black;*/
        height: 180px;
}

#navbar {

}

.ftex {
    position: relative;


}

#qqq {
    position: static !important;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-image:url('images/bg-fs-5.png');
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     height: 125px;
     width: 800px;
     /*padding:25px 0 0 0;*/
     /*padding-top: 50px;
     padding-left: 34px;*/
}

.ftex ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    /*border:2px solid yellow;*/
    width:1200px;

}

.ftex ul li {
    display:inline;
    padding-right: 170px; 
    font-family: 'Conv_LITHOSPRO-REGULAR';
    font-size: 20px;
    /*border:2px solid red;*/
    color:#ffbf81;
}

.ftex li a:link {
  color: #ffbf81;
  border-bottom:4px solid #ffbf81;
  }

.ftex li a:visited {
  color: #ffbf81;
  border-bottom:4px solid #ffbf81;
  }

.ftex li a:hover {
  color: #ffbf81;
  background:none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom:4px solid #ffbf81;
  }

.ftex li a:active {
  color: #ffbf81;
  border-bottom:4px solid #ffbf81;
  } 

.ftex ul li#ss {
    border-bottom:4px solid #ffbf81;
    padding-right:5px;

}


#footerBg {
    position: relative;
    bottom:-90px;
    left:-50px;

}

#foot {
    padding-top: 10px;
}


#foot img {
    display: block;
}

#foothome{
    padding-top:100px; 
}

#foothome img {
    display: block;
}


#numb1 {
    position: absolute;
    /*border:10px solid red;*/
    top:10px;

    right:-124px;
    /*z-index: 100;*/
    /*background:url(images/number2.png); */
}

#abt {
    position: relative;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    height: 400px;
    left:180px;
    top:-60px;

    z-index: -2;

}

#papersl {
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    top: 222px;
    z-index: -4;
}

.Navigation { background:background: rgb(246,248,249); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%, rgba(229,235,238,1) 46%, rgba(215,222,227,1) 65%, rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(246,248,249,1)), color-stop(46%,rgba(229,235,238,1)), color-stop(65%,rgba(215,222,227,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(245,247,249,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 46%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 65%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 46%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 65%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 46%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 65%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 46%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 65%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f8f9', endColorstr='#f5f7f9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */ 
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;

    box-shadow: -3px -5px 10px  #888888;
    font-size: 26px;

    /*position: relative;
    top:-50px;*/
    clear:both;

    font-family: 'Conv_LITHOSPRO-REGULAR';  

}

.Navigation ul li {  position: relative; list-style: none; padding: 17px 10px; }

.Navigation ul li a { font-size: 26px; color: white; text-decoration: none; }

.Navigation ul li:hover { background: url(images/hover.png) repeat-x; height: 43px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 2px black inset; padding: 20px 9px; border-left: 1px solid #a4a4a4; border-right: 1px solid #a4a4a4;} 

.Navigation ul li:hover { background: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; height: auto; border: none; }


.arrow-up { width: 0; height: 0; border-left: 10px solid transparent; border-right: 10px solid transparent; border-bottom: 15px solid #6a6a63; position: absolute; left: 20px; top: -15px; }

.Navigation  ul li .extended { position: absolute; top: 45px; left: 0; width: 220px; background: url(images/dropdownback.png); z-index: 1000; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); box-shadow: 0 0 8px black; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid white; display: none; color: white; }

.Navigation  ul li .extended img { display: block; margin: 5px auto 15px auto; -webkit-box-reflect:below 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.8, transparent), to(rgba(255,255,255,0.5))); }

.Navigation  ul li .extended a { font-size:14px;}

.Navigation  ul li .extended h2, .Navigation ul li .ultraNav h2 { padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px; font-size: 16px; text-shadow: 0 1px 2px black; color: white; background: url(images/headerback.png) repeat-x; height: 20px; border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px;  }

.Navigation ul li .extended span { padding-left: 10px; font-size: 11px; }

.Navigation  ul li .extended ul.smallNav { border-top: 1px solid rgba(141,141,141,0.50);  padding: 10px; height: 100px;  }

.Navigation ul li .extended ul.smallNav li { width: 200px; padding: 0; line-height: 22px; font-weight: bold; background: url(images/linkback.png) no-repeat; }

.extended ul li {float:left;}

.Navigation  ul li .extended ul.smallNav li:first-child { margin: 0; }

.Navigation  ul li .extended ul.smallNav li:last-child { margin-bottom: 10px; }

.Navigation ul li:hover .extended { display: block; }

.Navigation ul li ul li:hover a { color: white; } 


#navbar ul {
    list-style-position:inside;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}


#navbar ul li {     
        display: inline;
        padding:0 20px 0px 0px; 
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        list-style-type:disc;
    }

#navbar ul li.OP {
        /*list-style-image:url('images/order.png'); */
        padding-left: 15px;

}   

#navbar ul li.OP img {
    vertical-align: middle; 
}




#navbar li a:link {
  color: #EF174A;
  }

#navbar li a:visited {
  color: #BF4100;
  }

 #navbar li a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color:#D2D2D2;
  border-radius: 10px; 
  }

 #navbar li a:active {
  color: #918FBC;
  } 

li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}  

#navbar ul li.OP a {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.Navigation  ul li .extended ul.smallNav li a { color: #c7c7c7 !important; text-shadow: none !important;  } 

.Navigation ul li .extended ul.smallNav li a:hover { color: white !important;} 

.arrow-container { margin-top:-16px; height:16px;  }

fieldset {
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#main {
    border: medium none;
    /*height: 500px;*/
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 326px;
    font-family: 'Conv_LITHOSPRO-REGULAR';
}
.or1 input {
    background-color: #303030;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;

    font-size: 1.2em;
    height: 27px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    width: 316px;
}

.ico {
    float: right;
}

button {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #303030, #3A3A3A) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(48,48,48,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(58,58,58,1))); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(48,48,48,1) 0%,rgba(58,58,58,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(48,48,48,1) 0%,rgba(58,58,58,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(48,48,48,1) 0%,rgba(58,58,58,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(48,48,48,1) 0%,rgba(58,58,58,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#303030', endColorstr='#3a3a3a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;

    -webkit-border-radius: .2em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 79px;
}


button:hover {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #303030, #4B4B4B) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}

button:active {
    border: medium none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.note1 {

    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #F74E09;

}

#search-form { width: 190px; position: absolute; right: 100px;
    bottom:55px;
    visibility: hidden; display: block;}
#search { background: #b2a48c; border: 3px solid #402f1d; color: #2b1e11; height: 20px; line-height: 20px; width: 150px; padding: 2px 4px; position: absolute; top: 11px; left: 0}
#search-submit { background: #b2a48c url(images/search.png) no-repeat 12px 7px; border: 3px solid #402f1d; height: 50px; width: 50px; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; display:block;}
#search-submit img {
    display: block;
}
#search-submit:hover { background-color: #c7bba7;}

/* CSS3 */
#search { border-radius: 20px; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b2a48c), to(#9b8d74));
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b2a48c, #9b8d74);
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.2) 0 0 5px;
   display: inline;
   }
#search-submit { border-radius: 50px; -moz-border-radius: 50px; -webkit-border-radius: 50px; -mox-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;display:block;
    /* Webkit-transition */
    -webkit-transition-property: background-color; 
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s, 0.4s; 
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
    }
```

Comment: We're going to need some more information as to what your problem is so we can better help you out :)

Comment: What browser are you using? In what way does the screen flicker? I am assuming in reality your page contains a lot more than simply just `<p> Content blah </p>` ?  At a glance, you appear to have a spare set of `});` at the end of your jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking my CSS was pretty long, so I didn't post it. Here it goes.

Comment: @Jeemusu , I am testing it on both chrome and FF. The flicker on FF is twice that of Chrome.

Comment: @TheKraven you should move that `</body>` tag after the `</script>` tag. And also append to it missing `</html>` tag. And you can validate your page to find and fix all bugs, either in [online validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload) or [FireFox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/html-validator/).

Comment: My mistake, forgot to copy over the `</html>` tag. the validator errors were mainly missing `alt` attributes..

Comment: You've not actually said *what* flickers.  We need an example url, or jsfiddle to see the issue.

Comment: I managed to take a short clip on what happens when I load the homepage. http://www.screenr.com/h7E8

Answer (score 1):

Use css to set the visibility setting for body to hidden before the js is loaded then remove the property with js onload using jquery.
css:

```
  body { visibility: hidden;}
```

javascript:

```
  $().ready(function(){ $("body").css({visibility:'visible'})});
```

Comment: So instead of a few elements flickering on load, this solution flickers the whole page.

Comment: That is indeed true. In some cases this may be the desirable behavior. If you are aware of other solutions please feel free to post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, put this in testCSS.css...

```
#numb1 { visibility:hidden; }
```

or...

```
#numb1 { display:none; }
```

Whichever is more pleasing to you.

Doing that will hide the numb1 element before the page is displayed.  What you're doing lets the page load before hiding it and then fading it in, so it's briefly visible.

Comment: Did that in the CSS. sorry for not posting the CSS earlier.

Comment: You don't do it in the CSS above.

Comment: Oops,that's my old code. I tried it, the flicker is still there.