# Avoid flickering when changing existing DOM elements on page load event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following DOM element change function using vanilla JavaScript where I change the span element that contains some text string of the DOM with a page load event.

With the following code, the DOM elements are changed as expected. However, they still see a **minimal fraction of flickering** before the DOM element change for the variable `desktop` and `mobile`.

#### Example of the flickering scenario:

- I see the tag span "Text I want to change" for a fraction of second.
- I see the changed tag span "text1 changed" after the content has fully loaded.

I think this is happening because the DOM changes are applied when the DOM content of the page is fully loaded. I would like to hide the existing tag elements until the changes have been applied and then display them.

The elements structure for `desktop` and `mobile` I want to manipulate is like the following:

```html
<span class="first-headline target-span">Text I want to change</span>
```

See the concept below:

```js
var changesObj = {
  "us": {
    title: "text1 changed"
  },
  "eu": {
    title: "text2 changed"
  }
};

function changes() {
  var webshop = changesObj[window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]];
  console.log(webshop);
  var changesText;
  if (!webshop) {
    console.log('webshop not found');
  }
  changesText = webshop.title;
  
  if (document.querySelector('.target-span').innerText.length > 0) {
    var desktop = document.querySelector('.target-span');
    console.log(desktop);
    desktop.innerText = changesText;
    console.log(desktop.innerText);
    console.log("applied changes for dekstop");
  }
  if (document.querySelector('.target-span').innerText.lenght > 0) {
    var mobile = document.querySelector('.target-span');
    mobile.innerText = changesText;
    console.log(mobile.innerText);
    console.log("applied changes for mobile");
  }
}

function invokeChanges() {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    changes();
  });
}

invokeChanges();
```

Is there a way to initially hide the DOM element until the change to the existing element has been applied and then show it?

I was thinking of using something inline CSS rules like the following:

Set `.style.visbility='hidden'` and when the text content is changed to show it with `.style.visbility='visble'`.

But I'm not sure how this solution should be appropriately implemented in my code.

Comment: It's a bit hard to use the examples provided since they're missing a few variables (and elements), requiring some more effort to reproduce this locally. It would be helpful if you can provide a more reproducible example.

Comment: please provide a pen.

Comment: This most likely answers your question: [Removing the page flicker when loading javascript/css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966137/removing-the-page-flicker-when-loading-javascript-css). Your hypothesis was correct about setting it hidden in CSS then with JS setting it to visible. If this is okay to you as an answer, do let me know then I'll write it up since this is a bounty.

Comment: To avoid the initial flickering, You need to check the condition inside a *blocking script* in the head, where you add the corresponding class to the ´html´ tag. You need also to define a pseudo either `before` or `after`, where you can declare the needed text using the `content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case you need to wait until the DOM has been loaded before you can manipulate it. Using an even listener for `DOMContentLoaded` would be the way to go. So, three things need to happen:

1. Wait for the DOM to load
2. Find the elements and change the text
3. Make the elements visible. You can either use the property `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`. Difference is that with `visibility: hidden` the element will still take up space. So, the choice depends on the context.

In the first example I add a timeout so that you can see what the page looks like just before the text is changed. I also styled the `<p>` (`display: inline-block`) so that you can see the size of the hidden span.

```js
window.location.hash = "us"; // for testing on SO
var changesObj = {
  "us": { title: "text1 changed" },
  "eu": { title: "text2 changed" }
};

function changes(e) {
  //let webshop = changesObj[window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]];
  let webshop = changesObj[window.location.hash.substring(1)]; // for testing on SO
  if (webshop) {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.target-span')].forEach(span => {
      span.textContent = webshop.title;
      span.classList.add('show');
    });
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  setTimeout(changes, 1000);
});
```

```css
p {
  border: thin solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.target-span {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.target-span.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="first-headline target-span">Text I want to change</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span class="first-headline target-span">Text I want to change</span>
</p>
```

In the second example I combined all the code into one HTML page. Notice that the style is defined in the header. So, when the DOM is passed the CSS will be passed as well without having to load a external style-sheet (well, there are  [tricks for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload) as well, but out of scope for this answer).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    p {
      border: thin solid black;
    }
    .target-span {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .target-span.show {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    window.location.hash = "us"; // for testing on SO
    var changesObj = {
      "us": {title: "text1 changed"},
      "eu": {title: "text2 changed"}
    };
    
    function changes(e) {
      //let webshop = changesObj[window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]];
      let webshop = changesObj[window.location.hash.substring(1)]; // for testing on SO
      if (webshop) {
        [...document.querySelectorAll('.target-span')].forEach(span => {
          span.textContent = webshop.title;
          span.classList.add('show');
        });
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', changes);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <span class="first-headline target-span">Text I want to change</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="first-headline target-span">Text I want to change</span>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons as to why it's flickering, but two preventative steps you can take:

- Use `defer` on your script tag `<script defer>`, as this lets the browser handle the order your scripts are run instead of `DOMContentLoaded`. You also get to avoid the `changes` wrapper function.
- As suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966137/removing-the-page-flicker-when-loading-javascript-css) (and your own reasoning) attach inline CSS / a CSS file to the page to set the text as invisible, *then* mark it as visible
- If it doesn't affect the layout of your page too much, you can also opt to dynamically generate the element instead.

**However**, do note that regardless of any of these, these still require JS to be executed and may still have a delay. If you are able to use it, you may be interested in [prerendering](https://web.dev/rendering-on-the-web/) your webpage - from your JS code, it looks for the route name if its `eu` or `us`, which means your page is pre-renderable.

Answer (score 0):

Quick & Dirty:

Place the script tag just below your span tag:

```
<span class="first-headline target-span">Text I want to change</span>

  <script>
    var changesObj = {
      "us": {
        title: "text1 changed"
      },
      "eu": {
        title: "text2 changed"
      }
    };

    function changes() {
      var webshop = changesObj[window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]];
      console.log(webshop);
      var changesText;
      if (!webshop) {
        console.log('webshop not found');
      }
      changesText = webshop.title;

      if (document.querySelector('.target-span').innerText.length > 0) {
        var desktop = document.querySelector('.target-span');
        console.log(desktop);
        desktop.innerText = changesText;
        console.log(desktop.innerText);
        console.log("applied changes for dekstop");
      }
      if (document.querySelector('.target-span').innerText.lenght > 0) {
        var mobile = document.querySelector('.target-span');
        mobile.innerText = changesText;
        console.log(mobile.innerText);
        console.log("applied changes for mobile");
      }
    }

    changes();
  </script>
```

This way you avoid the asynchronous code part.

Comment: Instead of reordering, they can also just use `defer`.

Comment: @LeoDog896 I agree. Main goal is to avoid asynchronous code.